# Windows 8.1 Remote desktop (Android app) Connection error

Tags: router, remote-desktop, android, port

I am trying to set up remote access from my Android tablet to my notebook with Windows 8.1. I have d-link router DIR-600. I am getting Connection error when trying to log on. My Android tablet is connected to my home wifi network.

I have tried this on different wifi network (with the same tablet and notebook) and it worked well. So I guess there is something with my routers settings. How can I change settings on my ruter?

I know about port forwarding, but I need to keep dynamical IP.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Use the IP address instead of machine name as server.
- Turn off firewall on PC to test, then add a rule if needed.
- Use another PC with RDP client to see if that works.
- Ping the server PC.
- Use the administrator user for login.
- Add the user logging in to allowed RDP users.
- Insure RDP is enabled.
- If home edition you cannot do RDP into the machine. A hack is required.